# C# - Amazon SNS Subscribe Application endpoint to topic

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm implementing Amazon SNS service in my C# program. I found a code to create a Topic. I want to know if there is a way to subscribe Application Endpoint to topic.

Like **Applications -> Select Application ARN -> Select all Endpoint ARNs -> Other Endpoint Actions -> Subscribe endpoint to Topic**.

I want to complete this action through my C# code.

Thanks,
Anand.

Comment: I need to do something like that, have a C# application that need to subscribe to a topic in real time. What did you end with?

Answer (score 0):

1.Open the Amazon SNS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/.

2.Click **Create subscription**.

(a).The **Create Subscription** dialog box appears.

3.In the **Topic ARN** field, paste the topic ARN you created in the previous task, for example: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:111122223333:MyTopic.

4.In the **Protocol** drop-down box, select **Email**.

5.In the **Endpoint** box, type an email address you can use to receive the notification.

**Important**

Entourage Users: Entourage strips out the confirmation URL. Type an email address you can access in a different email application.

6.Click Create subscription.
[image]

7.Go to your email application and open the message from AWS Notifications, and then click the link to confirm your subscription.

Comment: Hi Shreyans, is there any way I can do these steps programmatically? That was my query actually.